# GMSMapView - why is my polyline being drawn under the street?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios, gmsmapview

I'm using GoogleMaps iOS SDK, and have followed the instructions to add a polyline to a map:

```
private func addRoute(to mapView: GMSMapView, history: ShipmentHistory) {

    let path = GMSMutablePath()
    path.add(history.currentState.location)
    for alert in history.alerts {
        path.add(alert.location)
    }
    let polyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
    polyline.strokeWidth = 5
    polyline.strokeColor = UIColor(asset: Asset.ColorAssets.appTint)
    polyline.zIndex = polylineBaseZIndex // value is 20
    polyline.map = mapView

}
```

Now I'm wondering why it's drawing this line underneath the street lines, as seen in the image:

[image]

Comment: How many `mapViews` is your controller managing?

Comment: one. just one...

Comment: I think the zIndex is causing you issues

Comment: could you elaborate?  I have to set it to something so that the lines are drawn under the dots.

Comment: I don’t think that is necessary, in my experience the polyline will be under the dot. Try to not set the zIndex

Comment: Well actually, is it a GMSCircle or a GMSMarker?

Comment: The issue has to do with polyline being under the street name.  Nothing to do with dots or markers.  that works fine.  I guess this is default behaviour to not obstruct the street name label.